# Junit keeps failing in Netbeans even when AssertEquals(1,1)

Tags: java, netbeans, junit

Basically I am trying to start a new project and correctly do unit testing with the whole thing. However I am about the completely give up on unit testing as the title says I'm getting a failed state even when I hard code AssertEquals(1,1).

```
@Test
public void testGetSeason() {
    System.out.println("getSeason");
    Episode instance = new Episode(1, 1, null);
    int expResult = 1;
    int result = instance.getSeason();
    assertEquals(1,1);  //assertEquals(expResult, result);
    // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
    fail(String.format("Episode getSeason Failed: expected %1$s actual %2$s", expResult, result));
}
```

So yeah anyone know why 1=1 causes a fail state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are calling the `fail()` method which will make your test fail. fail method is mostly used to fail a test if an exception was not thrown, by calling it in the try block.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. You'd think when you get "generated" code they'd add it to a try catch statement.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling fail() which will instantly cause your test to fail. Remove it and it will work.

I'm assuming you thought that fail() will simply output the message you provided if the assert failed, and you didn't realize that it actually fails the test itself. For this you can try using `assertEquals`, see this for more details: http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html

Comment: This is the first time that I've played around with JUnit. I'm more use to using the Unit Testing library's in C#.

Comment: @BrendanRusso I edited in an alternative that might help do what you're looking for. Also, taxis answer just loaded on my mobile, I didn't see it at first, but same thing. He answered first though.